# GOTO command returns "no such label"

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

```
@echo off
:start
setlocal enableextensions
title Lock your pc...
explorer.exe
call %cd%\badtrip.bat
goto start
```

When i do the last portion it says that label can't be found. I have tried using call instead and doing this with and without command extensions. Why can it not find the label start which is clearly defined. The name of this file is badtrip, so yes it is meant to be circular and spawn itself while also looping in each new instance.

Comment: Maybe `start` is reserved - try `top`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: There is not "reserved labels" in Batch files... If this file is the same called batch file, then this is a never ending loop at the `call` command and the `goto start` command is never executed.

Comment: It's a never ending loop if `badtrip.bat` doesn't exist. It will open explorer windows until your system crashes ...

Comment: And `setlocal enableextensions` inside the loop results on each loop run to push on stack current working directory, current states of command extensions and delayed expansion, the pointer to current environment table and creates a copy of the current environment table. This works only several times before Windows command interpreter exits batch processing because of a stack overflow.

Comment: @DavidPostill thats the goal and it does exist